# DistributionChart range extends beyond the data itself

Tags: plotting, graphics, distributions, visualization, charts

I have a larger data set and want to display it using [`DistributionChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributionChart.html).

```
dat = Flatten[{RandomReal[1., 10000], RandomReal[2., 2000]}];
DistributionChart[dat, PlotRange -> {0., 2.}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In my particular case min and max values are

```
Min[dat]
(* 0.0000359013 *)

Max[dat]
(* 1.99981 *)
```

**Why does the plot suggest values below the min and above the max?**

A [`BoxWhiskerChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html) of the same data works fine:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[dat, {"Median", {"MedianMarker", 1, Black}, {"Whiskers", Black},
{"Fences", 0.5, Black}}, PlotRange -> {0., 2.}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SmoothHistogram >>> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SmoothHistogram.html):

> [image]

[MaxExtraBandwidths >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxExtraBandwidths.html):

> [image]

Despite the red syntax highlighting, this option also works  in `SmoothHistogram`:

```
dat = Flatten[{RandomReal[1., 10000], RandomReal[2., 2000]}]; 

SmoothHistogram[dat, .1, "PDF", 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> 400,
 MaxExtraBandwidths -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {{-.5, 2.5}, {0., 1}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {-.5, 0}]
```

[image]

For `DistributionChart`, one would expect/hope that the option `Threshold` for the built-in `ChartElementFunction` `SmoothDensity` would work similarly, but ...  it doesn't (see [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11100/125)). So, one possibility is to build a custom `ChartElementFunction` that uses `SmoothHistogram` with the option `MaxExtraBandwiths` set to `{0, 0}`. The following is one such example -- which is meant to be suggestive as it needs to be refined/embellished in a number of ways.

```
ClearAll[cEF];
cEF[bw_: (.1), padding_: {0, 0}] :=
  Module[{color = Charting`ChartStyleInformation["Color"], sh},
    sh = SmoothHistogram[#2, bw, "PDF", MaxExtraBandwidths -> padding,
       Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> color, PlotStyle -> color][[1]];
    {EdgeForm[color], GeometricTransformation[sh,
      Composition[TranslationTransform[{2 #1[[1, 1]], 0}],
       ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}], RotationTransform[Pi/2]]],
     GeometricTransformation[sh, 
      Composition[TranslationTransform[{2 #1[[1, 1]], 0}],
       RotationTransform[Pi/2]]]}] &;
```

Usage:

```
DistributionChart[{dat, 1 + dat, 2 + dat}, ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
 ImageSize -> 400, GridLines -> {None, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}}, ChartElementFunction -> cEF[]]
```

[image]

```
dat2 = # + dat & /@ RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {5}];
charts = DistributionChart[dat2, ChartStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green, Yellow, Brown},
     ImageSize -> 400, GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 6]}, PlotRange -> {0, 6},
     ChartElementFunction -> cEF[#2, #],
     PlotLabel -> (Style[Row[{"bandwith : ", #2, "  max extra bw : ", #1}] , 20])] &;

Grid@Partition[charts @@@ Tuples[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {.2, .1, .05} }],3]
```

[image]

See also: [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46815/125) on a similar issue with `DistributionChart`.

Comment: This solution works best for my data. Bandwith is a very good option to tweak the look of the resulting plots and keeps everything between min and max. Thank you very much :)!

Comment: @Kardashev3, my pleasure. Thank you for the Accept.

Comment: A shift on the horizontal axis may be mastered using a numeric parameter in TranslationTransform - instead of 2, give 1. In some cases you may also need to limit horizontal PlotRange.

Answer (score 9):

Both, `DistributionChart` and `SmoothHistogram` are models using a "smooth kernel density estimate".

Consider the simplest case with two points only:

```
DistributionChart[{0, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
SmoothHistogram[{0, 1}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

For your data we get

```
dat = Flatten[{RandomReal[1., 10000], RandomReal[2., 2000]}];

DistributionChart[dat, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
SmoothHistogram[dat, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Again, because of the smoothing, some data exceed the upper and lower limits.

An alternative without smoothing is the classic `Histogram`:

[image]

**Update**

With less data

```
dat = Flatten[{RandomReal[1., 1000], RandomReal[2., 200]}];
```

you also could employ

```
DistributionChart[dat,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 ChartElementFunction -> "PointDensity",
 BarSpacing -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: What is odd is that `DistributionChart` doesn't seem to allow a definition of a Kernel and a bandwidth, as in `SmoothHistogram`. (Does it?) The problem could be solved by choosing a smaller bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Now I understand the result of the plot. PointDensity would indeed work for a smaller sample.

Answer (score 6):

You can show the histogram as per eldo's classic histogram above by using HistogramDensity for the ChartElementFunction.  Some datasets with outliers plot better with transformed data (such as log), but perhaps not this one.

```
dat1 = Flatten[{RandomReal[1., 10000], RandomReal[2., 2000]}];
cht1=Table[DistributionChart[dat1, PlotRange -> {0., 2.},ChartElementFunction-> (ChartElementDataFunction["HistogramDensity", "Bins" -> iCef]) ],{iCef,{"Scott",{"Log", "Scott"}}}]
```

[image]

Take a look at this questions for a ChartElementFunction Options:
[Control parameters of different styles of DistributionChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11097/control-parameters-of-different-styles-of-distributionchart/11100#11100)

Comment: HistogramDensity is indeed another good approach for the visualisation of such data.