# Distribution Chart plot error

Tags: plotting

Phenomena:
min max value mismatch in of `DistributionChart` plot. 
In this chart, we can see the minimum value is somewhere below zero.
However, the actual minimum of dataset is larger than 0.

[image: Wrong plot]

Minimum reproducible code:

```
distList = RandomVariate[WeibullDistribution[1.5, 2], 100];
Min[distList]
DistributionChart[distList]
```

Is there know bugs and quick fix?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until your observation has been confirmed by other users.

Comment: It's not a bug, but a sneaky feature. See this previous discussion: [`DistributionChart` range extends beyond the data itself](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60600/27951), of which this question might be considered a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. It looks more complicated than I supposed.